# Not able to test click event in new user-event 14.4.3 testing library in react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test a simple user click button where the counter will increase from 0 to 1. Here is my counter button

```
import { useState } from "react";

export const Counter = () => {
     const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
     return (
        <>
          <h1>{counter}</h1>
          <button onClick={() => setCounter(count => count + 1)} >INCREMENT +</button>
        </>)};
```

and corresponding test for it

```
import {render, screen} from "@testing-library/react"
import { Counter } from "./Counter";
import { user } from "@testing-library/user-event";
import "./Counter";

     test("renders count of 1 when clicking on INCREMENT + button", async () => {
          user.setup()
          render(<Counter />)
          const incrBtn = screen.getByRole("button", {
               name: "INCREMENT +"
          });
          await user.click(incrBtn);
          const countElmnt = screen.getByRole("heading");
          expect(countElmnt).toHaveTextContent("1");
     });
```

I am using the following dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/dom": "^9.3.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3"
  }
```

I get the following error
[error received in vs code terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS18O.png)
can someone tell me what i am doing wrong here?

I tried this command

```
npm install --save-dev @testing-library/user-event @testing-library/dom
```

to install latest version of user-event testing-library.

I am expecting a successful completion of click event test when I click on INCREMENT + button, the test should be successfully passed.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, it was related to package updating.

I simply uninstall and again install the 'user-event' library from terminal, hitting this command.
npm uninstall @testing-library/user-event
npm install @testing-library/user-event

and I got the updated package in package.json file
"@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",

```
   test("renders count of 1 when clicking on INCREMENT + button", async () => {
          const user = userEvent.setup()
          render(<Counter />)
          const incrBtn = screen.getByRole("button", {
               name: "INCREMENT +"
          });
          await user.click(incrBtn);
          const countElmnt = screen.getByRole("heading");
          expect(countElmnt).toHaveTextContent("1");
     });
});
```

and I added this code and it worked!
Thank you Lin for the inputs about user and userEvent imports.